# EF Core: The instance of entity type x cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{xId: }' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm running into this issue (specifically indicating that RecipeIngredient/RecipeIngredientId is the issue) while trying to seed a database with a user and a recipe. It occurs when I call `dataContext.Recipes.Add(recipe)` in my seeding method after creating/finding a user with userManager then creating a new Recipe. Here is the most relevant part of InitializeAsync in SeedData.cs:

```
    string adminEmail = "admin@example.com";
    string adminPassword = "Pa$$w0rd";
    
    AppUser? user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(adminEmail);
    if (user == null) {
        user = new AppUser { UserName = adminEmail, Email = adminEmail };
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, adminPassword);
    }
    
    if (dataContext.Recipes.Count() == 0) {

        Recipe recipe = new Recipe {
            RecipeId = "1",
            UserId = user.Id,
            Name = "Tarka Dal",
            Description = "Nulla turpis risus, mollis sed mi non, congue posuere enim. Fusce vehicula ligula nec nibh vehicula tempor. Maecenas accumsan quis mauris a imperdiet. Phasellus venenatis, dolor vitae venenatis aliquet, mi nisi consequat ligula, vel facilisis arcu eros id justo. Vestibulum id porta tellus, nec porttitor diam. Praesent hendrerit nulla sed eros finibus, eu sodales mauris semper. Praesent eros velit, sollicitudin a ex id, sagittis eleifend turpis. Pellentesque facilisis sem eu varius elementum. Sed ac justo dolor. Donec malesuada justo eu urna luctus, et cursus magna laoreet. Vivamus a accumsan risus. Nullam rutrum porta elementum. Curabitur lectus odio, euismod et dolor sit amet, efficitur elementum felis. Mauris quam sapien, commodo sed libero facilisis, cursus feugiat ligula.",
            Notes = "Donec quis ullamcorper erat, id tempor ante. Integer ut lorem viverra, laoreet orci nec, aliquam nisl. Fusce placerat nisl ac mauris condimentum, sed efficitur urna faucibus. Suspendisse laoreet laoreet malesuada. Quisque congue ut leo ac rhoncus. Aenean commodo dui ut urna ullamcorper tristique. Proin ac feugiat enim, vitae tempus magna. Nam suscipit luctus maximus. Sed laoreet dolor nibh, quis vestibulum leo facilisis a. Integer at mi convallis, porttitor leo non, eleifend enim. Mauris et dolor diam. Morbi metus ligula, pretium ac lectus in, tempus ullamcorper leo.",
            RecipeSteps = new List<RecipeStep> {
                            new RecipeStep {
                                Name = "Step 1",
                                Description = "Rinse Lentils",
                                RecipeId = "1"
                            },
                            new RecipeStep {
                                Name = "Step 2",
                                Description = "Add lentils to pot and add water",
                                RecipeId = "1"
                            },
                            new RecipeStep {
                                Name = "Step 3",
                                Description = "Bring to boil, adding water when necessary, keep on medium boil until lentils disintegrate.",
                                RecipeId = "1"
                            }
                        },
            RecipeIngredients = new List<RecipeIngredient> {
                            new RecipeIngredient {
                                IngredientName = "Lentils",
                                Amount = "4 cups",
                                ModifierPost = "soaked",
                                RecipeId = "1"
                            },
                            new RecipeIngredient {
                                IngredientName = "Water",
                                Amount = "to cover",
                                RecipeId = "1"
                            }
                        },
            Comments = new List<Comment> {
                                new Comment {
                                    UserId = user.Id,
                                    RecipeId = "1",
                                    Text = "Nice recipe."
                                }
                        }

        };
        
        dataContext.Recipes.Add(recipe);
        
        ...
```

I've seen a few proposed solutions:

1. Make sure the context is scoped: in my case the dataContext passed to the method is created in Program.cs like this:

`var dataContext = app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();`

2. Turn off tracking: It doesn't seem like this is a good solution in the first place, but hopefully it will help solve this to point out that my DbContext service is registered like this:

`builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opts => { opts.UseSqlServer(connectionString); opts.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking); });`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: since this runs before the site starts, I'd remove all async operations.  Just run everything synchronous and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: @pcalkins Good idea, unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything running on a fresh Db.

Comment: is "RecipeId" the primary key for Recipe?

Comment: @pcalkins That's right.

Comment: It looks like you do need to turn off tracking, this seems like the easiest and most effective way. Please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/181032/having-trouble-with-foreign-key-in-entity-cant-tra).

Comment: I think you'll need to add the user first, recipe 2nd, and then add steps and ingredients.  Let the DB choose the ID... (so don't set RecipeId... it'll make a UID for it)

Comment: @pcalkins that might have worked - what ended up working for me was moving all the seeding into the OnModelCreating method in the DbContext class. I'll update the post to reflect that. Thanks again!